# Return the length of the strings inside the array

Tags: arrays, swift, string, function

I need a function that will accept a list of string and a closure that returns the number of characters of each element from the given string list

Example string: ["aaa","baba","cacaca"]

return: [3,4,6]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `map` function and String's `count` function.

```
let array = ["aaa","baba","cacaca"]
array.map { $0.characters.count }
```

Comment: It work's but I want it to be a function that will accept array of strings

Comment: Why its not returning anything? i did it like this `let fruits = ["ORANGE","MANGO","APPLE"]

func getStringCount(strings: [String]) -> [Int] {
return fruits.map { $0.characters.count } }

var counts = getStringCount`

Comment: @Presmelito I wrote my code wrong, in yours it should say `return strings.map { $0.characters.count}}`

Comment: @Presmelito - `func getStringCount(strings: [String]) -> [Int] { return strings.map { $0.characters.count } } `

Comment: @Pierce Read up the docs on the `map` function, it's very useful and you can do a lot with it.

Comment: its says ERROR at line 11, col 17: missing argument label 'strings:' in call
getStringCount2(fruits)
                ^
                strings:

Comment: @Presmelito - that error is pretty straight forward, you need to put `strings:` when you call the method. `getStringCount(strings: fruits)`. That's it. You really should read about the basics of functions and methods in the Swift Docs. You're getting stuck on basic syntax issues here. You could also just put a _ at the front of your function declaration, like: `func getStringCount(_ strings: [String]) -> [Int] {` then you don't have to explicitly say `strings:` when you call the method.